# Create Literal type from constant variables

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I want to use "constant" variables in my typing definitions, something like this:

```py
FOO = "foo"
BAR = "bar"

@dataclass
class Event():
    name: Literal[FOO, BAR]
```

But that is illegal code for mypy.

This works, but then I cannot use the variables in my code:

```py
FOO = Literal["foo"]
BAR = Literal["bar"]

@dataclass
class Event():
    name: FOO | BAR

Event(FOO) # gives: Event(name=typing.Literal['foo'])
```

Is there a way to get this to work without defining FOO and BAR twice?

---

Impelenting Marks answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/76382060/5386216) works, but then mypy is not able to distinguish types based on the event name:

```py
class FooBar(Enum):
    FOO = "foo"
    BAR = "bar"

@dataclass
class StringEvent:
    name: Literal[FooBar.FOO]
    value: str


@dataclass
class NumberEvent:
    name: Literal[FooBar.BAR]
    value: int


def handle_event(event: StringEvent | NumberEvent):
    if event.name == FooBar.FOO:
        event.value.upper()  # should not give a mypy error

    if event.name == FooBar.BAR:
        event.value.upper()  # Should give a mypy error
```

Both both cases of `event.value.upper()` give the following mypy error: `Item "int" of "Union[str, int]" has no attribute "upper"`

Comment: `Literal["foo"]` is the *type*, not the actual string value. You would need to define the type and a value of the type separately: `FOOTYPE = Literal["foo"]; FOO: FOOTTYPE = "foo"`, which is even more repetitive but avoidable; see [Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76382060/1126841).

Comment: (`None` is a special case supported by `mypy` in that it can represent both the value and the type of that value, depending on context. I'm not aware of similar support for other singleton types.)

Comment: The context you provided makes things much more confusing. Why is `event.name == FooBar.BAR` an error if `event` accepts both types?

Comment: @matszwecja Not that. The union implies that `event.value` can be both `int` and `str`.

Comment: I am wondering why you are so keen on using the value of that `name` attribute as a type guard. Can you elaborate why you do not just want to do `isinstance(event, StringEvent)` for example?

Comment: @matszwecja `event.value` is of type int when `event.name` is `FooBar.BAR` and therefore `event.value.upper()` doesn't exist. But does when `event.name` is `FooBar.Foo`, because then `event.value` is a string. This works as expected when using `Literal["foo"]` and `Literal["bar"]` as type hints for `*Event.name`

Comment: @Daniil Fajnberg Because our code has very many event types and checking for both the event name and then also the event type just make mypy happy generates a lot of boiler plate code.

Comment: @QuintvanDijk Are you able to provide an example where `if isinstance(event, StringEvent):` check could not be used instead of `if event.name == FooBar.FOO:`?

Comment: I mean, why not just do [this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=256d78002d912b856dc20e3a68b5aa60) in the first place. Why do you need to distinguish the types based on an attribute value?

Comment: Because I have +/- 100 different event names, that map to a few different event types. The code already has a lot statements based on event.name (so `if event.name == "foo"`) adding the type check to all of those gets messy and adds to much code, just to make mypy happy. Of course you can nest the if statements, but still. Thanks for being critical, I'm not too sure if I'm doing the right thing from an architecture standpoint

Comment: When you compare the enum values as it is recommended (with `is`) then mypy accepts the first line and rejects the second with `error: "int" has no attribute "upper"` as it should

Comment: This wasn't mentioned here yet, but you can go other way around: given `Literal` type `T`, you can get its string values with `typing.get_args(T)`. It returns a tuple (1-tuple in your case), and `typing.get_args(T)[0]` will refer to first string in Literal definition.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the type is not the same as the value. One is a `Literal` type and the value is a string.

Just like @STerliakov is mentioning in a comment, the best way is to turn it on its head, by defining the type first and the constant string based on the type, as follows:

```py
from typing import Literal, get_args

FOO_TYPE = Literal["foo"]
FOO = get_args(FOO_TYPE)[0]
BAR_TYPE = Literal["bar"]
BAR = get_args(BAR_TYPE)[0]
```

It's a bit more verbose than I'd like and not so elegant, but at least you don't repeat yourself. One could also put this in a class and write a decorator to do this automatically:

```py
from typing import Literal

def const_literals(cls):
    # make a copy of vars because we change the dictionary during iteration
    for const, lit in dict(**vars(c)).items():
        setattr(cls, f"{const}_TYPE", Literal[lit])
    return cls

@const_literals
class Constants:
    FOO = "foo"
    BAR = "bar"

print(Constants.FOO)  # prints "foo"
print(Constants.FOO_TYPE)  # prints "typing.Literal['foo']"
```